# Is it able to echo parallel negative numbers in vim?

Tags: vim

In `h vim-script-intro`.
It says `-` will be interpreter as `minus` or `negative` depends on the situation.
Thus `echo -1 1` will result `-1 1`, and `echo -1 -1` will result `-2`.

Drove by my curiosity, I tried googled and stackoverflow-searched a bit about how to modify `echo -1 -1` so that it can echo `-1 -1`, but no result found.

Is it able to do that? How?

Answer (score 1):

You can surround it by quotes to stop vim from calculating the result

```
echo '-1 -1'
```

Comment: I believe these quotes turned them into string or something wired? Because `echo '-1 -1' -1` now results `-2`. Why this happened?

Comment: I did some experiments, that echo will still do arithmetical operation using the first number inside the quote with numbers outside of the quote.

Comment: Indeed, `echo -1 '-1' -1` results in `-1 -2`.